# How to monitor FCM token refresh with phonegap push plugin

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

As it is stated here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message#monitor-token-refresh FCM tokens can be refreshed in some cases but I don't see anything that deals with it in phonegap push plugin documentation.
Does someone know how is it solved in this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer I got from phonegap github: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2415 which states:

> The on('registration') event is fired if there is a token refresh.
>   Each time you get a registration event you need to check to see if the
>   value is different than the one you previously had. If so, send it to
>   the server.